# When you retrieve info from MySQL server using C#, the manipulation of the data is done with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

Like the title, I'm working (learning) with ASP.Net and C#, when I retrieve the data from MySQL server, how do I work on the client side?

The case: I have all the code in a `button_Click` method (function auto-generated), which connects to MySQL, queries the info and displays it in a textBox or any other ASP element. Once I have the data on the HTML, if I make another button with a click action in my CS file to manipulate that data, is the client running it or is the server?

I come from a JS/PHP environment I'm assuming that C# is like PHP, and all the code on C# has to be process in the server. If that's the case, how do I process data client-side.

Sorry about my English, any correction is accepted. ;)

In case it is like PHP, let's say I have all the data on a Grid and I need to loop through it to calculate something, I need to do it with C#? all the data will be send to the server and the back with the result? Is there something like JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. C# like PHP runs on the server side.  We do the coding in ASP.Net using C# programming language. ASP.Net will generate the HTML and write the html response to a response stream.

Comment: So, programinmg in ASP.net is really like streaming data? won't the server will overcharge?

Comment: ASP.Net does lot more than that. You write web services using ASP.Net, it provides lot of flexibility how do you want handel a http request and many more. When ever a decision is being made about the technology it's not only the rent of the server there are lot of other things comes into picture, like the availability of developers, existing system etc..

Comment: Got it, I don't want to turn this into a discussion and I respect your anwer, but I'm not concern about the rent, but the limits of the solution, each time the user hits a button to i.e. caluculate taxes in an invoice, the site will ask for a process to the server? it's a little disappointing for a technology that has a lot to offer, I know you can use Javascript on the client side to do the taxes calculation, but, is that the way to go? the best-practice?

Comment: My suggestion would be if the calculation logic or  algorithm is ok to  visible to  the user and also if you do not want save any data then do it at the client side. Otherwise go for server side programming.

Comment: And the way to do that is javascript? or there's a way of scripting with C# in client side. What the user could sniff is one of my concerns, so I'm with you about just proccessing this kind of data

Answer (score 0):

Any C# code that you write will be server side code. If you want to handle or manipulate data on the client side (within the browser), you have to use something like javascript or JS libraries.

In your example above the data that you put in textbox or any other control will be embedded in HTML (right click your page and see view source in browser). So you can add javascript to button2 to read the value from textbox and change them.

Comment: So the best-practice is to use a pure JS or a framework like angularJS or JQuery?